# How to access specific key:value for each object in array of objects using jQuery $.each?

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

Schema (MongoDB):

```
key0: [
  {
     skey1: "sval1",
     skey2: "sval2"
  },
  {
     skey1: "sval3",
     skey2: "sval4"
  },
]
```

getJSON() Response:

```
[Object { skey1="val1", skey2="val2"}, Object { skey1="val3", skey2="val4"}]
```

Question:

How to access value of `skey2` for each object?

jQuery (attempt):

```
my_var = results.key0

$.each(my_var, function(k,v) {
alert(v);
});
```

I think I need to do some sort of 'nested' `$.each` but not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/Yg5cg/4/

```
// aim:  to alert value of 'skey2' for each object

myArray = [{ skey1:"val1", skey2:"val2"}, { skey1:"val3", skey2:"val4"}]

$.each(myArray, function(k,v) {
  alert(v.skey2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var my_var = [{
    skey1: "sval1",
    skey2: "sval2"
}, {
    skey1: "sval3",
    skey2: "sval4"
}, ];
var len = my_var.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    $.each(my_var[i], function (k, v) {
        alert("key"+k+"value"+v);
    });
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Zqx/)